# Values of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ in ets in forecast package

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I am using the `forecast` package in R. I wanted to know how the `ets()` function finds the value of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

Is it by minimizing the SSE or some other criteria?

Comment: The question is clearly answered by the help for the function - `?ets`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is MLE. The argument `opt.crit` controls the optimization criterion. from the help file:

> opt.crit
>
> > Optimization criterion. One of "mse" (Mean Square Error),
> >       "amse" (Average MSE over first nmse forecast horizons), "sigma"
> >       (Standard deviation of residuals), "mae" (Mean of absolute residuals),
> >       or "lik" (Log-likelihood, the default).